# Very simple VBA error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I keep getting a syntax error in the following VBA function:

[image]

```
Function F_1(k_, x_)
    F_1 = (x_^3 - 3.0 * k_ * x_^2 + 3.0 * k_^2 * x_ - (5.0/7.0) * k_^3) / SQR(x_ - k_)
End Function
```

Anybody know what's happening?

Comment: post your code as text, not as a screenshot. Who wants to decipher the tiny font and make sense of it?

Comment: apologies @teylyn

Comment: I think you cannot simply use SQR as it is a worksheet function, not a VBA function. You need to use something like `Application.WorksheetFunction.SQR()`

Comment: @Aganju [Sqr is a VBA function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sqr-function)

Comment: Also there will be a runtime error if x_ < k_

Answer (score 5):

You need to add spaces before and after an operator, otherwise Excel cannot interpret it. So, e.g. instead of `x_^3` use `x_ ^ 3` etc.

You may also want to drop the `_` from the variable/parameter names. It is very unusual notation and may lead to confusion when you break long commands into several rows with the `_` sign.

Comment: Agreed on the note about the `_` as the end of the variable name. It took me a little longer than usual to just understand that's a name, not a line break or something else.